# Is it possible to revert back to "default" global namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, using-directives

Basically, I am working with some provided header files with the following format:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class bar
{
public:
    void printSomething(void)
    {
        cout << "This is an example." << endl;
    }
}
```

My question is, since I can't modify the provided header, how do I strip the `std` namespace in my files and go back to the default global namespace? I have tried "`using namespace ::;`" and "`using namespace ;`", but the the compiler isn't happy with either of those. Any ideas on how to force a clean slate with namespaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. That's why the `using namespace` clause is so evul. You could include those headers inside another namespace though:

```
namespace bleh {
    #include "library_that_uses_evul_using_namespace.h"
}
```

That will pollute only the `bleh` namespace.

Comment: Class declarations essentially work like namespaces in this regard, correct? Like with `class spam { #include "evul.h" }` only spam would have the tainted namespace created by "evul.h" and the global namespace would remain untouched?

Answer (score 5):

You can't get rid of a "using namespace". You can have multiple "using namespace " statements and they are additive.

However, you can wrap the malicious header into a namespace of it's own:

```
namespace Crap
{
    #include "maliciousHeader.h"
}
```

That way the "using namespace std" only applies to the namespace Crap. I'd recommend putting the above code into another header which is the header that you actually include in your program.

Comment: Good suggestion to sandbox the header within a namespace within another header. I think I will start doing this from now on.

Comment: Keep in mind it won't work if there's a cpp alongside the header because the Crap namespace becomes part of the identifier the linker uses to match declarations and definitions. Whenever you can, change the broken header file instead.